# delayed job - RES keep growing

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I have some tasks which needs to rub in background so i was planning to use delayedjob gem but before put in development, i wanted to rub simple TEST to see RES consumption.

Simple Helper with no code

```
module TestjobHelper
  def self.imageprocess(gb)
    gb = nil
  end
end
```

Putting into  delay job

```
TestjobHelper.delay(:queue => 'testjob').imageprocess('gb')
```

Running Delayed Job queue command

```
RAILS_ENV=development script/delayed_job -i testjob --queue=testjob start
```

Above sample program, gives keep growing RES value even if there is nothing to do in delayed job function.

RES Output:

http://prntscr.com/9v17ah

http://prntscr.com/9v18he

Comment: What does `RES` stand for? What do the numbers mean?

Comment: @spickermann RES stands for the resident size, which is an accurate representation of how much actual physical memory a process is consuming.

Comment: And what is your question? Are you surprised that loading records from the database and initializing ActiveRecord objects consumes RAM - even when they are thrown away right after that?

Comment: @spickermann yes, if you see my helper method, it simple one variable and no database connection even though memory keep growing

Comment: @spickermann myquestion is that what cause this much memory consumption in above program?

Comment: I read your two images like there was an increase of memory consumption of 172 Bytes. I would not even care about that. Why are you conserned about so little memory? Do I miss something?

Comment: @spickermann, Yes, this is test program but it goes up to 2 GB on production server

Comment: Okay, that is a new piece of information. You wrote in your question that you didn't use DJ in production yet and you did not provide the info that the memory usage is 2GB. Is it 2GB in prod with this test example? After how many runs? With Ruby and DJ version are your running? What are your `config.cache_classes` for that environment. Might make sense to add all that missing info into the question for other readers.